# Annotation on class generated with JaxB

Tags: java, xml, xsd, annotations, maven-jaxb2-plugin

In my binding file .xjb I've the following information.

```
    <jaxb:bindings node="xs:complexType[@name='mySuperKillerObject']">               
       <annox:annotateClass>@org.springframework.stereotype.Component</annox:annotateClass>
    </jaxb:bindings>
```

when I try to generate the sources, I've error message

> "Annotation class [org.springframework.stereotype.Component] could not be found."

I wonder I've to add the jar to xjc classpath but I don't know how.  In pom.xml?

Ideas?